# Permissions Problem with PowerShell Active Directory Query Script Against Multiple Domains

Tags: powershell, permissions, active-directory, authorization

We are using this simple script to enumerate all privileged users:

```bsh
'Domain Admins', 'Administrators', 'Enterprise Admins', 'Schema Admins', 'Server Operators', 'Backup Operators' |
    ForEach-Object {$groupName = $_; Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $_ -Recursive |
    Get-ADUser -Properties Name, DisplayName |
    Select-Object Name, DisplayName, @{n='GroupName';e={ $groupName }}}
```

However, the following error comes from the 'Administrators' group:

```
Get-ADGroupMember : The operation being requested was not performed because the user has not been authenticated
At line:2 char:38
+     ForEach-Object {$groupName = $_; Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $_ -Recursive |
+                                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Administrators:ADGroup) [Get-ADGroupMember], ADException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryServer:1244,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADGroupMember
```

I believe the problem is that we have two Active Directory Domains.  The Administrators group has accounts from the other domain.  Now both domains trust each other and are supposed to allow access to each other, but obviously something isn't working right.

The ideal solution would be to figure out how to fix the problem (permissions/AD setup).  If that's too complex, is it possible to limit the scope of the query to stay within the AD domain?  Then I could run the script on each domain.

Comment: If StackOverflow is the wrong place to post this and I should move this to ServerFault would someone mind confirming this is a good idea?

Comment: Have you seen the `-Credential` and/or `-Server` parameters on [Get-ADGroupMember](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/get-adgroupmember)?

Comment: @Theo We ran the script on a Domain Controller with an account with all privileges and got the same result so I don't believe that's it.  Let me know if you don't agree.